# VSCode - environment variable set in settings.json is undefined in Node debug terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I set an environment variable as such in settings.json:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "${env:HOME}/xyz.json"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"]
}
```

I can confirm that it is set correctly in the integrated terminal.

When I debug in Node, the same variable appears as undefined. Is this expected behavior?

I can get around this by also defining it in launch.json as such:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
            "env": { "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS": "${env:HOME}/xyz.json" }
        }
    ]
}
```

But what I would ideally like is to define it in only one place and be done with it.

Yes, I could also define it in .profile and have it passed to VSCode through the "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["-l"] option in settings.json but there are other reasons I don't want to do this.

Thoughts?